# Evidence for continuous residence to apply for UK citizenship as a EU student?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, naturalization

One of the requirements for applying for British citizenship through naturalization is:

> During the last five years you must not have been outside the United
>   Kingdom for more than 450 days (about 15 months);

How is that proven as an EU citizen? Does the government already automatically know how long you stayed in the UK for (using their airport records) if you're a EU student?

Or do you need to show your flight tickets?

Please explain to me how this process works exactly. Thanks!

Comment: Crossposted on Expatriates.SE: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17640/evidence-for-continuous-residence-to-apply-for-uk-citizenship-as-a-eu-student

Comment: They'll look at any evidence that you can give them that you've been in the UK. I gave them five P60s which prove that some employer paid taxes over five years for someone claiming to have my name and claiming to live where I claim to live, which is enough. As a student, you should have records of taking exams (passed or failed wouldn't matter). You should have been paying rent. You should have been registered with a doctor, etc. etc. Using airport records is totally unreliable; I can fly in to the UK from Rome and drive back with a friend the next day without anyone noticing it.

Comment: Phone bills in your name, electricity bills in your name, your bank account with payments to local shops about every week, that's all good evidence you were in the country. And there are no specific rules about evidence, anything that is believable and shows you were in the UK will count.

Comment: @gnasher729 perhaps you should post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

### You swear a declaration to that effect

The authorities may or may not investigate at the time. However, if you lie and it emerges that you lied, your citizenship can be revoked as it was issued on false pretences.

Comment: I think legally it may not be "revoked", but it will have never existed.

Comment: @gnasher729 the analogous act in the US is "revocation of naturalization" if I recall correctly.